# Absolute path on Xtext project

Tags: path, xtext, absolute-path, xtend

I wanted to know how I can get the absolute path of a file which is inside my project not in the application running.

For example this one:

```
C:\Users\Mr\Documents\Example\org.xtext.example.mydsl\src\example.txt
```

I have tried with paths like:

```
val file = new File("relative path");
val absolutePathString = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

or

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

But all of them retrieves me Eclipse's path and not my project's path.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you inside eclipse? are you in standalone mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not need to be a file. Assuming you have a default eclipse with default filesystem and talk about a file in a project you may have a look a at these

```
public void doit(Resource r) {
    URI uri = r.getURI();
    if (uri.isPlatformResource()) {
        IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(uri.toPlatformString(true)));
        file.getLocation();
        file.getLocationURI();
        file.getRawLocation();
        file.getRawLocationURI();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but this is not what im looking for. Let's say i have the default Xtext project which recognices Hello name !. Before even running the application, i want to load on my project a .txt file on my ServiSegGenerator.xtend or a .java class from the project. I wanted to put this file on src/folder but im not be able to get that path because I always get C:\eclipse or a path from the running application. Thanks another time for your time ^^

Comment: Well but that is a class.getResource / class.getResourceAsStream usecase

Comment: And which project do you mean

Comment: And what if you call the generator in standalone mode

Comment: Hi! I already solved it using class.getResourceAsStream and then using a BufferedReader on the file loaded. It's way easier that way instead of trying to get the full path to the src project. Thanks!